# Running executables present in the PATH environment using execve

Tags: c, posix

I'm writing a simple shell in C.
To execute a command, a shell basically creates a child process and subsequently *execs* the same to run the command.

I am using the function execve as follows:

```
execve(argList[0],argList,envList);
```

Here argList and envList are char*(string) arrays with (say) the following values:

```
argList={"ls",NULL}
envList={"/bin",NULL}
```

I figure that since *ls* is present as an executable in /bin directory, the required exec should have the same effect as ls (on a LINUX system ofcourse).

The execve command however is not able to execute for executables present in directories in the environment.

The same works perfectly for running executables in the current working directory.

Where am I going wrong?

---

***Conclusion***: I had mistaken environment to be entirely something else. [apologies :)]
The environment array is responsible for *setting* the environment for the **child process**.
Thus, as pointed out by Jim, the correct procedure is to set the environment variables in the format:

```
envList = { "HOME=/root", PATH="/bin:/sbin", NULL }
```

as is also explained [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_toc.html#SEC406).

Further, in order to achieve the above mentioned result using execve (instead of execvp),
as Nemo explains, we could always make repeated calls to the directories in PATH. execve would fail if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
envList={"/bin",NULL}
```

This is incorrect. `envList` provides the environment strings for the `exec`-ed program; it is not a search list or a path list. A correct `envList` would be more like

```
envList = { "HOME=/root", "PATH=/bin:/sbin", NULL }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this can be the accepted answer. The proposed changes to `envList` does nothing for `execve`s ability to find and execute the program.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, there is no such ability. Note that there is no question in the title--the title refers to something that is not actually doable. The only question is "Where am I going wrong?" ... the answer is in part in this answer, in part in Nemo's answer, in part in the comments by Nemo and me under that answer, and in part in the OP's conclusion. If you want to bundle all that up into an answer of your own, or to edit this answer to include all of it, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 6):

`execve` does not search `PATH`.  You need to use `execlp` or similar.  See [the POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) for details.

On Linux, you might want `execvpe`, but that is non-standard.

(Also, none of these functions are part of standard C.  You should add a platform-specific tag to your question, like "posix" or "linux".)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried using execlp and it does work. However, for the sake of understanding, I also want to try out doing the same using execve. Therefore, I first got the environment using getenv("PATH") and then split the paths into various directories storing the same in the array envList. As I understand, this command should have looked into each of those PATH directories and ran the executable if it was present in any of them.
NOTE: I suspect this might have something to do with the first argument of execve being a file name as opposed to a path. But I am not sure yet.

Comment: If you manually prepend each element of `PATH` to the file name and then try `execve` over and over, that should work...  `execve` uses a full file name as the first argument.  If the file name does not start with `/`, it will be looked up relative to the current working directory; `execve` simply does not search the `PATH`.

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal envlist doesn't work anything like that ... it provides the environment strings for the execed program