# Path expansion in execve()

Tags: c, shell, path, execve

I followed what was said in a different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290556/running-executables-present-in-the-path-environment-using-execve).

I have used `execve()` with an environment variable `PATH`, set it to `/bin`, in order to be able to call commands without using the absolute path. But the function `execve()` still doesn't recognize the commands such as `ls`. Only `/bin/ls` works.
What could be the issue?

```
char *envList[3] = {"HOME=/root", "PATH=/bin", NULL };
execve(command[0], command, envList);
```

Comment: Since you already found this question, _why didn't you read the answers?_

Comment: You're looking for [`execvp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) or [`execvpe(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvpe.3.html) — the former is standardized by POSIX but the latter is not.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the `execve` syscall works. It will never look at `PATH` or any other environment variables to search for the executable to execute. You will have to provide a valid absolute or relative path.

Furthermore, setting the environment only affects the new program that is executed, not the current one. So even using the `execvpe()` library function that emulates the path resolution of a shell looking at `PATH`, it will look at *the current value of the environment variable `PATH`*, not the one being passed as environment to the new process.